# I cant translate a math problem into python

Tags: python, math

I'm currently learning python, and I just can't wrap my head around this.
I was taking some python classes, and one of the program examples required the user to enter two inputs  `v0 = 100` and `theta = 30` (gave them the values in the example) and use the following formulas to get the flight time of a ball, and Horizontal distance reached

v0x = v0 * cos⁡(theta)
v0y = v0 * sin⁡(theta)
v0y * t- 1/2 * 9.8 * t^2 = 0
d = v0x * t

My problem is I'm not sure how I'm supposed to convert the third formula into python code. I'm  assuming I need to solve for  T, but how would I go about doing that in python.

so far all I can do is this

```
v0 = 100
theta = 30
v0x = v0 * math.cos(theta)
v0y = v0 * math.sin(theta)
t = ???
d = v0 * t

print(f"Flight time of the ball is: {t}")
print(f"Horizontal distance reached by the ball is: {d} " )
```

Comment: You won't be able to directly translate that to Python in its current form. Have you thought about how you might rearrange the formula?

Comment: You need to isolate `t` algebraically in order to get the calculation for a `t = ...` assignment. (e.g. using a [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation))

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a bit of physics but , you will have to calculate the t(time) equation to feed it into python , some what like below

```
v0y * t- 1/2 * 9.8 * t^2 = 0
t * ( v0y - 1/2 * 9.8 * t) = 0
t = 0 or v0y - 1/2 * 9.8 * t = 0 
v0y = 1/2 * 9.8 * t
t = 2 * v0y / 9.8
```

So to convert that into python

```
t = 2 * v0y / 9.8
```

Overall code will look like

```
import math

v0 = 100
theta = math.radians(30)
v0x = v0 * math.cos(theta)
v0y = v0 * math.sin(theta)
t =  2 * v0y / 9.8 
d = v0 * t

print(f"Flight time of the ball is: {t}")
print(f"Horizontal distance reached by the ball is: {d} " )
```

Comment: Added the complete code for your reference, OP's code was missing degree to radian conversion to be used in the calucations